# spring boot starter email null pointer exception

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, email, nullpointerexception

I'm using spring boot starter dependency to send some emails. But it throws `NullPointerException`. I tried logging the email objects and they are available.

Here's the code in [github](https://github.com/sef-global/scholarx/pull/119)

Here's the email objects

```
claudia.prescott@mail.com
SimpleMailMessage: from=Sustainable Educational Foundation - SEF; replyTo=null; to=claudia.prescott@mail.com; cc=; bcc=; sentDate=null; subject=APPROVED; text=MENTEE_SELECTION
dave.walters3@protonmail.com
SimpleMailMessage: from=Sustainable Educational Foundation - SEF; replyTo=null; to=dave.walters3@protonmail.com; cc=; bcc=; sentDate=null; subject=PENDING; text=MENTEE_SELECTION
michele.moore3@protonmail.com
```

Here's the error log: https://pastebin.com/QFLM9vwi

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please remove static from

```
@Autowired
private static JavaMailSender emailSender;
```

as static members cannot be autowired. Also EmailUtil is not a spring bean so autowiring won't work.

Updated:

EmailUtil:

```
@Component
public class EmailUtil {
    
    @Autowired
    private JavaMailSender emailSender;
```

ProgramService:

```
@Service
public class ProgramService {

       @Autowired
       private EmailUtil emailUtil

......
public Program updateState(long id) throws ResourceNotFoundException {
      emailUtil.sendSimpleMessage(email);
```

Comment: removing static won't allow me to access it from the `programService` @Ganesh Modak `Non-static method 'sendSimpleMessage(org.sefglobal.scholarx.model.Email)' cannot be referenced from a static context`

Comment: Mark EmailUtil with @Component and autowire it in ProgramService class and then access the method on emailUtil instance non statically.

Comment: Still having the same error. Can you check my github code please?